# Angular http not rerurn value on first request

Tags: angular, spring-boot, api, spring-data-jpa

When first call this function, it return no thing but when i try again it return true data.
idk why,
My Exam:

```js
getUserAccountInfo(token: string | null): Observable<UserAccount> {
        return this.http.get<UserAccount>(
          AUTH_API + '/get_user_account_info?token=' + token
        );
      }
```

```js
    public getCurrentUserAccount(): any {
        let token = this.getToken();
        let check = new UserAccount();
        this.authService.getUserAccountInfo(token).subscribe({
          next: (data) => (this.currentUserAccount = data),
          error: (err) => console.log(err),
        });
    
        return this.currentUserAccount;
      }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning before the subscription finishes. You need to wait for it somehow. In the example below I wait for it using a promise:

```js
export class MyService {
  async getCurrentUserAccount(): any {
    let token = this.getToken();
    let check = new UserAccount();
    this.currentUserAccount = await this.authService
        .getUserAccountInfo(token)
        .pipe(first()) // Import first() from rxjs
        .toPromise(); 

    return this.currentUserAccount;   
  }
}
```

```js
export class App {
  async ngOnInit() {
    const userAccount = await this.myService.getCurrentUserAccount();
  }
}
```