# Cannot set results of an api call to a variable in an Angular 1 application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, post

I am trying to call an api, and set the results to a variable. I am able to successfully make the call and see the data when I log it in the console, but later when I try to use the variable it is undefined.

Here is the relevant code:

```
        var postParams = {
            "code": input.Code,
            "number": input.Number
        }

        var result;

        try {
            $http.post("/api/DetailAPI/GetDetails?code=" + input.Code + "&number=" + input.Number, postParams).success(function (details) {
                console.log(details);
                result = JSON.parse(details);
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        console.log(result);
```

The first console.log(details) shows the data I am expecting listed as "Object". When console.log(result) is called result is undefined.

I have tried with and without JSON.parse() and get the same result either way.

I know the api call is working, since I can see the data in the console. The issue is that I cannot store this data in my result variable.

How do I get Angular to actually put the data I get from the api call into a variable?

Comment: If you are trying to get data shouldn't the HTTP verb/method be GET instead of POST...

Comment: Maybe. But I didn't write the api. And I double checked it is a POST.

Comment: $http.post is asynchronous, so isn't your console.log(result) statement executed before the success callback? Therefore 'result' is not yet set at the point you run console.log(result)?

If you'd like to use your the 'details' response I think you either have to do it inside the .success block or alternatively use async/await syntax to make it synchronous.

Comment: I don't think that is the case because console.log(details) shows the data I am expecting, so the call must be complete. It is only after I try to use the data that I run into issues. Specifically, after setting result to be the same as details, result is still undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are consoling the result variable before it has been defined.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I declare the result variable prior to making the call, then set it in the call.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71278702/angular-http-not-rerurn-value-on-first-request/71278880#71278880   Please refer this

Comment: I don't think that is the same issue. I am able to see the data returned from the api. I just cannot set it to a variable.

Comment: ` var postParams = {
            "code": input.Code,
            "number": input.Number
        }

        var result;

        try {
            $http.post("/api/DetailAPI/GetDetails?code=" + input.Code + "&number=" + input.Number, postParams).success(function (details) {
                console.log(details);
                result = JSON.parse(details); 
           console.log(result);
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
`

Comment: I promise I am trying to understand what you are saying. What does this code snippet demonstrate?